# How to reset a variable used in a function that accepts it as a parameter?

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a problem, I created a multiplication game in Python using functions but when I check if the user has enough points to change level, the point counter ("compteur") does not reset to 0. I'm a beginner so it It's quite possible that the error is stupid, but I don't understand...
[You can see this in Python tutor, but I tried adding "return compteur" but that doesn't work either...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oocCm.png)

Here is the function code:

> ```
>  def update (compteur) :
>         global level
>         if compteur == 20 :
>             level+=1
>             print("Niveau",level-1,"terminé. Passage au niveau",level,"!")
>             compteur = 0
>             return compteur
> ```

And the whole code:

```
###############################################################################
#  Importation de fonctions externes                                          #

import random

###############################################################################
#  Définitions locales de fonctions                                           #

compteur=0

def calcul (max) :
    '''
    Cette fonction calcule une mutiplication avec des valeures aléatoires, elle
    admet un seul paramètre :
        - Maximum des valeures alétoires
    Elle retourne le nombre saisi par l'utilisateur ainsi que le nombre calculé
    par l'ordinateur.
    '''
    global compteur
    global nb_user
    global nb_result
    valeur_1=random.randint(1, max)
    valeur_2=random.randint(1, max)
    nb_result=valeur_1*valeur_2
    print(valeur_1,"*",valeur_2)
    print("Debug =",nb_result,)
    nb_user=int(input("Entrer votre réponse : \n"))
    return nb_user
    return nb_result
      
def verif (nb_user, nb_result) :
    '''
    Cette fonction vérifie si le résultat saisi par l'utilisateur est égale au
    résultat attendu, elle admet donc deux paramètres :
        - Nb_user
        - Nb_result
    Elle retourne l'indice de réussite.
    '''
    global compteur
    if nb_user == nb_result :
        compteur+=1
        print("Bonne réponse !")
    else :
        compteur-=1
        print("Mauvaise réponse !")

def update (compteur) :
    global level
    if compteur == 20 :
        level+=1
        print("Niveau",level-1,"terminé. Passage au niveau",level,"!")
        compteur = 0
        return compteur
    

###############################################################################
#  Corps principal du programme


# Déclarations des variables 

level=1

# Debut

print("Bienvenue dans le Jeu des multiplications !")
while level == 1 :
    calcul(10)
    print(compteur, level)
    verif(nb_user, nb_result)
    update(compteur)
while level == 2 :
    calcul(20)
    print(compteur, level)
    verif(nb_user, nb_result)
    update(compteur)
while level == 3 :
    calcul(50)
    verif(nb_user, nb_result)
    update(compteur)
while level == 4 :
    calcul(100)
    verif(nb_user, nb_result)
    update(compteur)
while level == 5 :
    print("Bien joué ! Tu es venu à bout du jeu.")
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: You should really try to write code without using `global`. Manipulating data from an outer scope in this way makes debugging hard and reuasability of the code even harder.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @Matthias , my teacher told me to do this, but I end up with more problems than anything else... I'm trying to learn Python on my own to avoid this kind of weird thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each time, you call `update(compteur)` you have to assign back the value to `compteur`:

Replace:

```
update(compteur)
```

By:

```
compteur = update(compteur)
```

You have to indent back the `return compteur`:

```
 def update (compteur) :
        global level
        if compteur == 20 :
            level+=1
            print("Niveau",level-1,"terminé. Passage au niveau",level,"!")
            compteur = 0
        return compteur  # Remove one tab
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, so I did that but a new error appeared, now the console shows me this: 
in verif compteur+=1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'
So what should I do?

Comment: @Astrium. I updated my answer. Can you check it? Bon courage :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup @Corralien ! Mais au final depuis j'ai réussi à corriger mes erreurs tout seul et j'ai exactement utilisé la méthode que tu me proposes ! Mon programme fonctionne parfaitement :)